How to write out multiple text files from multiple instances of LaTeX environments for Literate Programming
Did find: Different approach to literate programming for LaTeX
but it's focused on writing out LaTeX .cls and .sty files --- I would like a simple solution which:

typesets the code
writes out the code to a specified file (I need at least 3 different files), either appending it (if that file has been written to previously) or creating a new file (for the first instance)

Using: Write environment body verbatim to a file
I did manage:
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{listings}
\lst@RequireAspects{writefile}

\lstnewenvironment{readme}{%
  \lst@BeginWriteFile{readme.md}%
}
{%
  \lst@EndWriteFile% closes output file
  \noindent\includegraphics[page=2, width=\linewidth/3]{readme.pdf} 
  \noindent\includegraphics[page=3, width=\linewidth/3]{readme.pdf}
  \noindent\includegraphics[page=4, width=\linewidth/3]{readme.pdf}
\verbatiminput{readme.md}
}
\makeatother

which works for one file:

but it depends on reading the file back in to set it, which doesn't work for incremental adding to a file.
I'd like something a bit more flexible for the other files which will need to be written out piecemeal and assembled on the fly, and I keep getting hung up on the difficulty of both writing out/appending to a file and preserving the contents of the environment in some fashion and then resetting/re-using it in a verbatim or similar environment.
An interface something like to:
\begin{code}[w]{gcodepreview}{py}
#!/usr/bin/env python
\end{code}

\begin{code}[a]{gcodepreview}{scad}
function getxpos() = xpos();
function getypos() = ypos();
function getzpos() = zpos();
function gettzpos() = tzpos();
\end{code}

(which of course would put the relevant code in two separate files and would then allow a similar coding to append to said files) would be great --- I just can't find or figure out the hooks to make everything come together as I'm envisioning it.
One thing I've been wondering is if this couldn't be done more easily using Lua.... or maybe the afore-mentioned file could be adapted to more general programming.
For using Lua I did find:
In LuaLaTeX, how do I pass the content of an environment to Lua verbatim?
and I've managed to get the text from the Lua variable typeset nicely and written out to a file.
EDIT: I've previously been using docstrip and the docmfp package:
https://github.com/WillAdams/gcodepreview/blob/main/gcodepreview.dtx
as described at:
https://old.reddit.com/r/LitProg/comments/1cf8x56/literate_programming_using_docmfp_for_python_and/
(as a baseline) but would like something a little more flexible with syntax highlighting in the editor.
I currently have the code from the above link where I have managed to get it to display (by reading the file in from listings) and I've tried to edit it to also write out or append the file based on variables, but I've broken things to the point where there isn't even a log...
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{luacode*}
do 
  local mybuf = ""
  local filename = ""
  local aorw = ""
  function readbuf( buf )
   print("buf=" .. buf)
    i,j = string.find(buf,"\\end{writecode}")
    print(i,j)
    if i==nil then
     mybuf = mybuf .. buf .. "\n" 
     print("[" .. mybuf .. "]")
     return ""
    else 
    return nil
    end
   end

  function startrecording()
    luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer', readbuf, 'readbuf')
  end

  function stoprecording()
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback('process_input_buffer', 'readbuf')
    local buf_without_end = mybuf:gsub("\\end{writecode}\n","")
    out = io.open('file.txt','w')
    out:write(buf_without_end)
    io.close(out)
    out = io.open(filename,aorw)
    out:write(buf_without_end)
    io.close(out)
  end

end
\end{luacode*}

 \lstalias{scad}{c}
 \lstalias{py}{python}

\newenvironment{writecode}[3][a]{\directlua{SetAorW(#1)}\directlua{SetFileName(#2.#3)}\directlua{startrecording()}}{\directlua{stoprecording()}\lstset{language=\fext}\lstinputlisting{file.txt}
}

\begin{document}
Begin.

\begin{writecode}[w]{gcpreview}{py}
    #!/usr/bin/env python
\end{writecode}

End.
\end{document}

and if I could just get working lua code to append or write to a file as specified from TeX things should then work.

The doc/docstrip documentation system can do what you want for the writing of the code to files, appending etc through its \generate macro. I am not too sure what you want to do with the append though. Can you extend your example to describe it?  However, you probably better off to write the code in normal editors and then use something like tcolorbox documentation (listings or minted) to produce the documentation.

I am currently using a .dtx file and the mfp package: https://github.com/WillAdams/gcodepreview --- it works okay, but it's not as flexible as I'd like, and I'm tired of the grey wall of text in the editor which makes my making syntax errors more likely (and commenting/uncommenting/commenting is tedious even w/ commands for it in TeXshop).

A further consideration is that a more typical/normal .tex setup for Literate Programming would make it easier to use TeX editors and associated tooling --- I'd really like to use LyX (and I find the whole R/Knittr thing confusing)

Can you provide a complete example for people to play with? Note that you can use an editor which does proper syntax highlighting for .dtx files. And docstrip etc. doesn't use R/Knitr. You can append code to files the way e.g. the aux is built up, but that's not verbatim. Lua can take the content of a file, change it and write it back, so appending isn't a problem. No idea about doing that verbatim, though.

Added the code I had copies from the provided link and rephrased the question --- hopefully this is explicit enough. Arguably, just being able to write out/append would be workable --- I could write out the text twice, once to a temp file which was read back in as shown in the first example.

Maybe it helps taking a step back: What do you want to achieve on a more abstract level, without fixing already the technology? Instead of using LaTeX as the driver, it is maybe easier to use something else on top and use TeX only as processor for some of the files.

What I want to do is write a book, which happens to be about a programming tool which I am making --- I would like to use LaTeX in a more natural fashion than docstrip allows, and I believe Lua makes this achievable.

"I'd really like to use LyX (and I find the whole R/Knittr thing confusing)" Really? In LyX ue knitr is just load de Rnw (knitr) module, then Insert → Custom Inset → Chunk o S/R expression, set your options in case of a chunk (optionally, worth the redundancy)  type the R code  (e.g.: 2+3).  Depending of the options, you will see in the pdf only the R code (2+3) with syntax highlight,  or only the output of the R (by default in S/R expresions)  of both things (by default in chunks). There are few options fr the chunks, so this is the easy part. The hard  part is know what R cannot make.

I think the big problem for me w/ R and knitr is that they don't line up with the current project toolset I'm working on and that they are tightly coupled and I haven't been able to find a good page which describes how to adapt it to general-purpose usage for arbitrary programming languages.

@WillAdams knitr support many other languages as Python (e.g.: here, Julia, C++, SQL, Stata, Ruby, Octave, Fortran, Bash (e.g.: here), etc. via the engine option. Run in R   names(knitr::knit_engines$get()) to know all the engines availables in your system.

The desired feature is also possible using regular LaTeX, which I am more familiar with. See this example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsimverb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{listings}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \doc_copy_file_content:nN  #1#2
{
    \ior_open:Nn \g_tmpa_ior {#1}
    \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_tmpa_ior
    {
        \iow_now:Nn #2 {##1}
    }
    \ior_close:N \g_tmpa_ior
}

\cs_new:Npn \doc_read_file_lines:nN  #1#2
{
    \ior_open:Nn \g_tmpa_ior {#1}
    \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_tmpa_ior
    {
        \seq_put_right:Nn #2 {##1}
    }
    \ior_close:N \g_tmpa_ior
}

\cs_new:Npn \doc_save_file_lines:NN  #1#2
{
    \seq_map_inline:Nn #1 {
        \iow_now:Nn #2 {##1}
    }
}

\seq_new:N \l_doc_prev_lines_seq

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mycode}{mmm}
{
    \XSIMfilewritestart{\jobname-mycode.vrb}
}
{
    % firstly, we write the verbatim body to a temporary file
    \XSIMfilewritestop
    % then, we do different things based on mode
    
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
    {
        {w}
        {
            % writing mode
            \iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {#2}
            \doc_copy_file_content:nN {\jobname-mycode.vrb} \g_tmpa_iow
            \iow_close:N \g_tmpa_iow
        }
        {a}
        {
            % append mode
            % first, read from the output file and save the contents
            \seq_clear:N \l_doc_prev_lines_seq
            \doc_read_file_lines:nN {#2} \l_doc_prev_lines_seq
            \seq_show:N \l_doc_prev_lines_seq
            \iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {#2}
            % write all saved lines to output
            \doc_save_file_lines:NN \l_doc_prev_lines_seq \g_tmpa_iow
            % write current content to output
            \doc_copy_file_content:nN {\jobname-mycode.vrb} \g_tmpa_iow
            \iow_close:N \g_tmpa_iow
        }
    }
    {
        \GenericError{}{unknown~mode~"#1"}{}{}
    }
    
    \lstinputlisting[language={#3}]{\jobname-mycode.vrb}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\parindent=0pt

Write mode:
\begin{mycode}{w}{some-file.py}{python}
def my_code(self, other):
        pass
    def my_code(self, other):
        pass
\end{mycode}

Append mode:
\begin{mycode}{a}{some-file.py}{python}
        def my_code(self, other):

        
                pass
            def my_code(self, other):


            
                pass
\end{mycode}

Read back:
\lstinputlisting[language={python}]{some-file.py}

\end{document}

The output:

The previous approach needs to read the existing content from file every time when appending, which can be slow. An alternative way is to save the body to separate files and merge them together in the end with \MergeAllFiles:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsimverb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{listings}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \doc_copy_file_content:nN  #1#2
{
    \ior_open:Nn \g_tmpa_ior {#1}
    \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_tmpa_ior
    {
        \iow_now:Nn #2 {##1}
    }
    \ior_close:N \g_tmpa_ior
}


\prop_new:N \g_doc_counter_lut_prop
\tl_new:N \l_doc_counter_tl

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mycode}{mmm}
{
    \XSIMfilewritestart{\jobname-mycode.vrb}
}
{
    % firstly, we write the verbatim body to a temporary file
    \XSIMfilewritestop
    % then, we do different things based on mode
    
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
    {
        {w}
        {
            % reset counter
            \prop_gput:Nnn \g_doc_counter_lut_prop {#2} {1}
            \iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {#2-1.vrb}
            \doc_copy_file_content:nN {\jobname-mycode.vrb} \g_tmpa_iow
            \iow_close:N \g_tmpa_iow
            
        }
        {a}
        {
            % append mode
            % get and increment counter
            \prop_get:NnNF \g_doc_counter_lut_prop {#2} \l_doc_counter_tl
            {
                \GenericError{}{invalid~filename~to~append~("#2")}{}{}
            }
            \tl_set:Nx \l_doc_counter_tl {\int_eval:n {\l_doc_counter_tl + 1}}
            \prop_gput:NnV \g_doc_counter_lut_prop {#2} \l_doc_counter_tl

            % write current content to output
            \exp_args:NNx \iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {#2-\l_doc_counter_tl.vrb}
            \doc_copy_file_content:nN {\jobname-mycode.vrb} \g_tmpa_iow
            \iow_close:N \g_tmpa_iow
        }
    }
    {
        \GenericError{}{unknown~mode~"#1"}{}{}
    }
    
    \lstinputlisting[language={#3}]{\jobname-mycode.vrb}
}

% call this function to merge all subfiles to one file
\cs_new:Npn  \MergeAllFiles #1
{
    \prop_get:NnNF \g_doc_counter_lut_prop {#1} \l_doc_counter_tl
    {
        \GenericError{}{invalid~filename~("#1")}{}{}
    }
    \iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {#1}
    \int_step_inline:nn {\l_doc_counter_tl}
    {
        \doc_copy_file_content:nN {#1-##1.vrb} \g_tmpa_iow
    }
    \iow_close:N \g_tmpa_iow
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\parindent=0pt

Write mode:
\begin{mycode}{w}{some-file.py}{python}
def my_code(self, other):
        pass
    def my_code(self, other):
        pass
\end{mycode}

Append mode:
\begin{mycode}{a}{some-file.py}{python}
        def my_code(self, other):

        
                pass
            def my_code(self, other):


            
                pass
\end{mycode}

\MergeAllFiles{some-file.py}

Read back:
\lstinputlisting[language={python}]{some-file.py}

\end{document}


When I run this w/ LuaLaTeX (This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (MiKTeX 23.1)) I get:
(./latexcode-mycode.vrb)
The sequence \l_doc_prev_lines_seq contains the items (without outer braces):

{def my_code(self, other):}
{        pass}
{    def my_code(self, other):}
{        pass}.
 }


It is debug information. Let me remove it.

there's already a core package called doc, so you should use a different name for this module.

Thanks! I'm going to test this out this evening --- looks very promising!

I incorporated this as: https://github.com/WillAdams/gcodepreview/blob/main/literati.sty and have been using it for: https://github.com/WillAdams/gcodepreview/blob/main/gcodepreview.tex which has been working quite well. Thanks!

@WillAdams Glad to know! As a matter of fact, I think manual counter updates such as \addtocounter{gcpy}{32} can also be automated.

I tried, but I kept getting random off-by-one errors --- I really don't mind having to do it, since it integrates well with my iterative programming style  (but would be glad of a robust solution if anyone else finds this sort of thing desirable).
At some point I hope to make a layout for LyX, which I would like to think would make this even more approachable to other folks.
